# Does the zero ideal contain the product of prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It is simple to show that non-trivial ideals contain the product of non-zero prime ideals, but is it the case for the zero ideal as well?

Answer (score 1):

Take $F$ a field, and let $R=F\times F$. Then $P=F\times\{0\}$ is a prime ideal (in fact, it is maximal), as $R/(F\times\{0\})\cong F$ is a field. Symmetrically, $Q=\{0\}\times F$ if a prime ideal of $R$. Now notice that $PQ$ is the zero ideal.

Comment: I'm confused - why am I allowed to choose $R$ s.t. it is the cartesian product of a field with itself?

Comment: @TomasAhlberg You are asking if it is possible for the zero ideal to contain a product of nonzero prime ideals. I gave you a specific example of a ring in which the zero ideal contains a product of n nonzero prime ideals.  Why would I not be allowed to construct an example as I see fit? If you had a specific ring in mind, then you forgot to say so in your question. Your questions asks simply if you can have a ring where it happens, and I showed you a ring where it happens.

Comment: Apologies - my question was intended for all Noetherian commutative rings.

Comment: @TomasAhlberg You are still not making much sense to me. There are rings where the product of nonzero ideals is *never* a nonzero ideal (for example, in $\mathbb{Z}$). In such rings, no product of nonzero prime ideals could possibly be contained in the zero ideal. There are rings where the product of some ideals, possibly maximal/prime might be zero (as I showed). What exactly did you mean to ask?

Comment: @TomasAhlberg Both $\mathbb{Z}$ and the ring above are Noetherian.